# Typescript throwing error on basic class component in usage with Redux connect wrap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-typescript

Having weird typescript failure:

> Argument of type 'typeof Filter' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
> Type 'typeof Filter' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<never, any>'.
> Construct signature return types 'Filter' and 'Component<never, any, any>' are incompatible.
> The types of 'props' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'Readonly & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)

with below basic code:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "typesafe-actions";

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  common: state.common,
});

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element[];
  } & ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;

type State = {
  showFilter: boolean;
};

class Filter extends React.Component<Props, State> {
   render() {
     return <>{this.props.children}</>;
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Filter);
```

I really don't know why this is happening. Any pointers on it are highly appreciated! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Filter);`